# Analysis with SQL based on transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL tables:

**1. ItemLevel Table**

```
SiteID   BusinessDate   ItemName   UnitsSold   UnitsSale   ItemNo  OrderNo
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        16/05/2019     Beef         1             5        10001    122-1
1        16/05/2019     Chicken      9             18       10002    122-1

1        16/05/2019     Beef         2             5        10001    122-4
1        16/05/2019     Chicken      2             6        10002    122-4
1        16/05/2019     Beans        4             8        10004    122-4

2        16/05/2019     Beef         2             5        10001    122-2
2        16/05/2019     Chicken      1             6        10002    122-2

3        16/05/2019     Bread        3             5        10003    122-3
3        16/05/2019     Beans        7             17       10004    122-3
```

**2. Master Item Table**

```
ItemNo    FullName   MenuCategory 
---------------------------------
10001       Beef      Group1    
10002       Chicken   Group1  
10003       Bread     Group2   
10004       Beans     Group2   
10005       Orange    Group3
```

**Expected Result**

```
ItemNo    FullName   MenuCategory    SoldwithGroup1     SoldwithGroup2   SoldwithGroup3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10001       Beef      Group1            5                    2                  0
10002       Chicken   Group1            12                   2                  0
10003       Bread     Group2            0                    3                  0                  
10004       Beans     Group2            4                    7                  0
10005       Orange    Group3            0                    0                  0
```

The above result, we are listing all the menu items from Master Item table as rows wise and each of these items are checked against different category to get the total units sold.

**Example:** we are checking how many beef items (unit sold) that went together with either Beef or Chicken (Group1) for each order and similarly for the other columns (oldwithGroup2, SoldwithGroup3)

we got 5 units sold under column SoldwithGroup1 because we checked the beef ItemNo (10001) that went together with either beef itself (because same item fall under same category)  or chicken which matches order nos (122-1, 122-4 & 122-2).

Comment: The numbers in the results table seem to have nothing to do with the original data, making it really hard to understand the logic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff we got 5 units sold under column SoldwithGroup1 because we checked the beef ItemNo (10001) that went together with either beef itself (because same item fall under same category) or chicken which matches order nos (122-1, 122-4 & 122-2).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to follow, because the values do not add up in the result set.

That said, for each item, it does make sense to look at the number of other items sold *in the same order* by group.  I suspect that is what you want.

This is a rather complicated self-join:

```
with ilg as (
      select il.*, mi.group
      from itemlevel il join
           materitem mi
           on il.itemno = mi.itemno
     )
select mi.itemno, mi.fullname, mi.MenuCategory,
       sum(case when ilg2.MenuCategory = 'Group1' then ilg2.unitssold end) as group1,
       sum(case when ilg2.MenuCategory = 'Group2' then ilg2.unitssold end) as group2,
       sum(case when ilg2.MenuCategory = 'Group3' then ilg2.unitssold end) as group3
from masteritems mi left join
     ilg
     on mi.itemno = ilg.itemno left join
     ilg ilg2
     on ilg.orderno = ilg2.orderno and ilg.itemno <> ilg2.itemno
group by mi.itemno, mi.fullname, mi.MenuCategory
```

Comment: in the output of colmun group1 i don't want to count how many units sold were gone under Group1 instead it should sum the total units of beef item with Group 1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that first calculates the sold units per MenuCategory within the same order.

Then uses that to conditional SUM the UnitsSold, depending on the MenuCategory.

```
SELECT ItemNo, FullName, MenuCategory,
 SUM(CASE WHEN MenuCategory = 'Group1' AND Grp1 > UnitsSold THEN UnitsSold WHEN MenuCategory != 'Group1' AND Grp1 > 0 THEN UnitsSold ELSE 0 END) AS SoldWithGroup1,
 SUM(CASE WHEN MenuCategory = 'Group2' AND Grp2 > UnitsSold THEN UnitsSold WHEN MenuCategory != 'Group2' AND Grp2 > 0 THEN UnitsSold ELSE 0 END) AS SoldWithGroup2,
 SUM(CASE WHEN MenuCategory = 'Group3' AND Grp3 > UnitsSold THEN UnitsSold WHEN MenuCategory != 'Group3' AND Grp3 > 0 THEN UnitsSold ELSE 0 END) AS SoldWithGroup3
FROM
(
    SELECT l.OrderNo, itm.ItemNo, itm.FullName, itm.MenuCategory, l.UnitsSold,
    SUM(CASE WHEN itm.MenuCategory = 'Group1' THEN l.UnitsSold ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY l.OrderNo) AS Grp1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN itm.MenuCategory = 'Group2' THEN l.UnitsSold ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY l.OrderNo) AS Grp2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN itm.MenuCategory = 'Group3' THEN l.UnitsSold ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY l.OrderNo) AS Grp3
    FROM Item itm
    LEFT JOIN ItemLevel l ON l.ItemNo = itm.ItemNo
) q
GROUP BY ItemNo, FullName, MenuCategory
ORDER BY ItemNo;
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/QOBB80388)